# Not waiting the minimum stipulated wait time

Tags: java, awaitility

The following test works when I use `Thread.sleep()`.

```
  @Test
  public void closeableTimer() throws InterruptedException {
    Timer timer = new DefaultTimer(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.count()).isEqualTo(0);
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.totalDuration()).isEqualTo(Duration.ZERO);
    try (Timer.Timed sample = timer.start()) {
      Thread.sleep(500L);
    }
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.count()).isEqualTo(1);
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.totalDuration()).isGreaterThan(Duration.ZERO);
  }
```

But if I use `Awaitility` instead for same test, it throws following error. Why? The code using `Awaitility` is using `atLeast(500 ms)`.

> Condition was evaluated in 108 milliseconds which is earlier than
> expected minimum timeout 500 milliseconds
> org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException

```
  @Test
  public void closeableTimer() {
    Timer timer = new DefaultTimer(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.count()).isEqualTo(0);
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.totalDuration()).isEqualTo(Duration.ZERO);
    try (Timer.Timed ignored = timer.start()) {
      await().atLeast(Duration.ofMillis(500L)).until(() -> true);
    }
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.count()).isEqualTo(1);
    Assertions.assertThat(timer.totalDuration()).isGreaterThan(Duration.ZERO);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a misunderstanding of the API.

The [documentation for `atLeast`](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#at-least) says:

> In case the condition is fulfilled before the duration specified by `atLeast` an exception is thrown indicating that the condition shouldn't be completed earlier than the specified duration.

In other words, this test asserts that the condition shouldn't return `true` before 500 milliseconds have passed — that it should take *more than* half a second to run — but the condition returns `true` immediately.

If you're trying to assert that the condition returns true in *less than* 500 milliseconds (the much more common case) you want to use `atMost` instead of `atLeast`.

If you're simply trying to insert a 500ms pause, `Thread.sleep` is a perfectly fine way to do it.

Comment: Using `atMost`, I think the condition would need to change to `() -> timer.count() == 1`.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what the OP is trying to test, but I think they just want a sleep!

Comment: I think they can save themselves 392ms :-)

Comment: I am looking to simply insert a 500ms pause, but using Awaitility.

Comment: What’s wrong with `Thread.sleep`?